# Accessibility friendly alternative to title attribute in HTML

Tags: html, accessibility

I am trying to make a website accessibility friendly by including `aria-label` attribute. I also have a `title` attribute for the tool-tip feature. I feel having two attributes is a bit redundant and would like just one attribute that can provide me both tool-tip and accessibility functionalities.

Having just `aria-label` is losing me tool-tip which is required for us. Is there an alternative that can give me both the above features ?

Comment: are you using a custom tooltip or are you simply meaning that when you hover the item the native browser `title` text on mouseover appears?

Comment: the latter one @GrahamRitchie. not any custom tooltip

Comment: Just remove the title attribute, it actually serves no real purpose anymore. Make sure your link (I am assuming it is a link because you are using `title`) is descriptive. If it isn't a link then you probably shouldn't have a title on there in the first place.

Comment: if you want to add a fiddle / example of your use case I can help further, I am making some assumptions as you don't say what you are labelling and why.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people use mobile phones to surf the web, so unless you have an application that is only used on computers, a lot of people won't benefit from the tooltip anyway and is actually not considered an accessible tool.

A lot also depends on what you want the tooltip to be at:

1. For a link, I would suggest to make the text of the link as clear as possible so everybody understands. (screenreaders often make an overview of all links on a page. So prevent the text "click here" because the person would not know what is behind it if there are five links with this name on the page).
2. For an icon button, I would suggest you use the aria-label or use icon together with text.
3. An image should just have an "alt" attribute to explain, so also no title needed.

I don't know if there are other use cases but my guess is that it would not be necessary anywhere else. There are nearly always alternatives.